# Simple SQL Search tweak

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am playing around with PHPFreaks "Simple SQL Search" script. I was wondering how to refine the search methods after a query has been submitted.

Let say I have submitted a search term like "music", the search query will give me the result of all the data in the database that contains the term "music" but lets say I want to search the term "music" and once the results have shown up I want to refine the search and looks for all the results under music that are in the category "rock" or "rap". I want to do this using a list of selected options.

Here is the working script from PHPFreaks, I included it so users here could also use this script if need be:

```
$error = array();
$results = array();


if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
   $searchTerms = trim($_GET['search']);
   $searchTerms = strip_tags($searchTerms); // remove any html/javascript.

   if (strlen($searchTerms) < 3) {
      $error[] = "Search terms must be longer than 3 characters.";
   }else {
      $searchTermDB = mysql_real_escape_string($searchTerms); // prevent sql injection.
   }

   // If there are no errors, lets get the search going.
   if (count($error) < 1) {
      $searchSQL = "SELECT sid, sbody, stitle, sdescription FROM simple_search WHERE ";

      // grab the search types.
      $types = array();
      $types[] = isset($_GET['body'])?"`sbody` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
      $types[] = isset($_GET['title'])?"`stitle` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
      $types[] = isset($_GET['desc'])?"`sdescription` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';

      $types = array_filter($types, "removeEmpty"); // removes any item that was empty (not checked)

      if (count($types) < 1)
         $types[] = "`sbody` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'"; // use the body as a default search if none are checked

          $andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?'AND':'OR';
      $searchSQL .= implode(" {$andOr} ", $types) . " ORDER BY `stitle`"; // order by title.

      $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$searchSQL}");

      if (mysql_num_rows($searchResult) < 1) {
         $error[] = "The search term provided {$searchTerms} yielded no results.";
      }else {
         $results = array(); // the result array
         $i = 1;
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)) {
            $results[] = "{$i}: {$row['stitle']}<br />{$row['sdescription']}<br />{$row['sbody']}<br /><br />";
            $i++;
         }
      }
   }
}

function removeEmpty($var) {
   return (!empty($var)); 
}
?>
```

The results:

```
 <?php echo (count($error) > 0)?"The following had errors:<br /><span id=\"error\">" . implode("<br />", $error) . "</span><br /><br />":""; ?>
      <form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="searchForm">
         Search For: <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo isset($searchTerms)?htmlspecialchars($searchTerms):''; ?>" /><br />
         Search In:<br />
         Body: <input type="checkbox" name="body" value="on" <?php echo isset($_GET['body'])?"checked":''; ?> /> | 
         Title: <input type="checkbox" name="title" value="on" <?php echo isset($_GET['title'])?"checked":''; ?> /> | 
         Description: <input type="checkbox" name="desc" value="on" <?php echo isset($_GET['desc'])?"checked":''; ?> /><br />
                 Match All Selected Fields? <input type="checkbox" name="matchall" value="on" <?php echo isset($_GET['matchall'])?"checked":''; ?><br /><br />
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search!" />
      </form>
      <?php echo (count($results) > 0)?"Your search term: {$searchTerms} returned:<br /><br />" . implode("", $results):""; ?>
```

I hope someone can lead me on the right direction here. I am somewhat familiar with PHP/MySQL and looked online everywhere but cannot figure out a way to refine the search results using this script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to refine the search results.

1. Save/serialize the search (resulting row-set) to disk/session, so you can search that in case the user adds anything to the search params. In this szenario you need to make sure, the user did not alter the "base" search params. If he did, you might run another base-search first and afterwards pull your refined result (genre specific entries) out of the result.
2. Add the new search param to some base-query-string and let the database do that refined search.

In both cases, you end up with a result, which is refined. I would go for the second option, in which you don't need to care about previous search params. You just add your "genre" to the query and you should be done.